# CSS3 Transition not working

Tags: css, css-transitions

I couldn't get transitions to work on [this page](http://ctuchicago.squarespace.com/), anybody has any idea why?

```
div.sicon a {
    transition: background 0.5s linear;
    -moz-transition: background 0.5s linear; /* Firefox 4 */
    -webkit-transition: background 0.5s linear; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-transition: background 0.5s linear; /* Opera */
    -ms-transition: background 0.5s linear; /* Explorer 10 */
}
```

Comment: Is this what you need: http://jsfiddle.net/vSUQP/16/

Comment: What actually are you trying to do with background?

Comment: looks great to me anyway on the page so can't see what the issue is.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Transition is more like an animation.

```
div.sicon a {
    background:-moz-radial-gradient(left, #ffffff 24%, #cba334 88%);
    transition: background 0.5s linear;
    -moz-transition: background 0.5s linear; /* Firefox 4 */
    -webkit-transition: background 0.5s linear; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-transition: background 0.5s linear; /* Opera */
    -ms-transition: background 0.5s linear; /* Explorer 10 */
}
```

So you need to invoke that animation with an action.

```
div.sicon a:hover {
    background:-moz-radial-gradient(left, #cba334 24%, #ffffff 88%);
}
```

Also check for browser support and if you still have some problem with whatever you're trying to do! Check css-overrides in your stylesheet and also check out for `behavior: ***.htc` css hacks.. there may be something overriding your transition!

You should check this out: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp

Answer (score 80):

A general answer for a general question... **Transitions can't animate properties that are auto.** If you have a transition not working, check that the starting value of the property is explicitly set.

Sometimes, you'll want to animate `height` and `width` when the starting or finishing value is `auto`. (For example, to make a `div` collapse, when its height is `auto` and must stay that way.) In this case, put the transition on `max-height` instead. Give `max-height` a sensible initial value (bigger than its actual height), then transition it to 0.

Comment: Good to know. I just replaced max-height with "none" instead of the scrollHeight + "px" because the inner div changes size during expand/collapse, but this prevented the animation from working... You saved me a lot of research time. :)

Comment: Can't believe it was this simple. I was setting the property to "" in my JS, setting it to "0" instead worked perfectly.

Comment: This is what was causing the issue for me. I wanted a transition on 'top', but without explicitly setting default 'top' value to 0, the transition effects weren't firing. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Exactly my issue. Thanks!

Comment: perfect.. setting initial value worked for me

Comment: I read 6 different tutorials and nowhere it was mentioned about 'auto', which is extremely important. Thank you.

Answer (score 38):

For me, it was having `display: none;`

```
#spinner-success-text {
    display: none;
    transition: all 1s ease-in;
}

#spinner-success-text.show {
    display: block;
}
```

Removing it, and using `opacity` instead, fixed the issue.

```
#spinner-success-text {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 1s ease-in;
}

#spinner-success-text.show {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: Although the outcome of `opacity: 0`, `visibility: hidden` and `display: none` is relatively the same, it should be noted that `display: none` affects the overall layout of the page, whereas the former merely hide the element but keep the layout as if the element was there.

Furthermore, click events and event propagation remain when using `opacity` and `visibility`, so be careful. You may want to set a proper `pointer-events` value.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a `<script>` tag anywhere on your page (even in the HTML, even if it is an empty tag with a `src`), then a `transition` must be activated by some event (it won't fire automatically when the page loads).

Answer (score 1):

HTML:

```html
<div class="foo">
    /* whatever is required */
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
.foo {
    top: 0;
    transition: top ease 0.5s;
}

.foo:hover{
    top: -10px;
}
```

This is just a basic transition to ease the div tag up by 10px when it is hovered on.
The transition property's values can be edited along with the class.hover properties to determine how the transition works.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using react and you run into this problem, make sure your component is kept in a different file other than the parent component. What I mean is:

```js
const Parent = () => {
    const ChildComp = () => (
    // element whose transition wont work
    )
    return (
        <div>
           <ChildComp />
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score -11):

Some browsers do not support the code. Maybe try using a different browser