# css transition on mouseover

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have the following css for my drop down menu in my banner:

```
#nav-menu li a
{
    background-image:url('../images/menu_background.png');  
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
    background-position: left top;
    height: 35px;
}


#nav-menu li a:hover
{
    background-image:url('../images/menu_background_hover.png');  
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
    background-position: left top;
    height: 35px;

}
```

It works fine, except that I would like some animation effect when I hover over the `<li>` tag. Currently, it just replaces the background colour of the `<li>` when i hover over it.

I tried the example code below which changes the margin-left of the li tag but I do not know how to animate the css transition on hover:

```
$j(document).ready(function () {

    //When mouse rolls over
    $j("#nav-menu li").hover(function () {

        $j(this).filter(':not(:animated)').animate({
            marginLeft: '9px'
        }, 'slow');
    },

    function () {
        $j(this).animate({
            marginLeft: '0px'
        }, 'slow');
    });

});
```

Thanks a lot for any suggestion.

Comment: I think this post is the proper solution for your problem,

<a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2983957/animate-background-image-change-with-jquery">http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2983957/animate-background-image-change-with-jquery</a>

Comment: CSS3 might be enough for your needs. See http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/ or http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_transitions.asp

Comment: use css instead of javascript.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7924038/css3-transition-not-working/8183269#8183269

Comment: Thanks css3 transition seems a good idea

Answer (score 1):

A quote from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2983957/animate-background-image-change-with-jquery),

> Blockquote
>   I guess you would have to work around this by not using genuine background-images, but div elements containing the image, positioned using position: absolute (or fixed) and z-index for stacking. You would then animate those divs.
>   Blockquote

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, am opting for css3 animations :)

Answer (score 0):

I got this working by removing the `j` after the `$` in the variable names.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/XjxBj/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //When mouse rolls over
    $("#nav-menu li").hover(function () {
        $(this).filter(':not(:animated)').animate({
            marginLeft: '9px'
        }, 'slow');
    },

    function () {
        $(this).animate({
            marginLeft: '0px'
        }, 'slow');
    });
});​
```